# How to count repeat values in multiples columns with a select

Tags: oracle, validation, plsql, plsqldeveloper

i have the **position_table** table:

```
     CODE_POSITION   NAME      GRADE    VALIDITY    DATE ELIMINATION    LEVEL
1    AAAA01          MANAGER   10       01/03/2016  31/12/2999          HIGH
2    BBBB01          ANALYST   09       01/03/2016  31/12/2999          LOW
3    CCCC01          STAFF     05       01/03/2016  31/12/2999          HIGH
4    BBBB01          ANALYST   09       01/03/2016  31/12/2999          HIGH
5    AAAA01          MANAGER   10       01/03/2016  31/12/2999          LOW
6    DDDD01          INTERN    01       01/03/2016  31/12/2999          HIGH
7    DDDD01          INTERN    01       01/07/2016  31/12/2999          LOW
```

I use this query to find and count the same code_position:

```
select code_position, count(code_position)
from position_table
group by code_position
having count(code_position) > 1;
```

And this is the result:

```
    CODE_POSITION   COUNT(CODE_POSITION)
1   AAAA01          2
2   BBBB01          2
3   DDDD01          2
```

**Note:**

1. The AAAA01 code is repeated twice and has the same date of validity and grade.
2. The BBBB01 code is repeated twice and has the same date of validity and grade.
3. The DDDD01 code is repeated twice and have different date of validity.

Now i need to check which **code_position** is repeated and if they have the same **validity** date and **grade** to. Like: AAAA01 and BBBB01.

Comment: Is this mysql or oracle? Please tag it accordingly  !

Comment: Just add those columns on the select and on the group by.

Comment: Ok, but now i have to include in the condition the max grade and the max validity, how could i do? @jorge-campos

Comment: @dcieslak already answered you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use more then one condition in `GROUP BY`. If you use more conditions, all will be compared and just grouped if identically.

```
SELECT
    code_position,
    COUNT(code_position),
    validity,
    grade
FROM position_table
GROUP BY
    code_position,
    validity,
    grade
HAVING COUNT(code_position) > 1
```

Comment: How I can do if i wan to verify the maximum degree and the maximum date in the same query? @dcieslak

Comment: @spikeTJ What column is the degree? And what date are you referring to? There are two on you table. If you know the columns, just add max(grade), max(date) to the select list.